# Where is `javaParen` defined?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I want to write my own java syntax file for more customization, But can't find the definition of `javaParen`, it certainly isn't defined in default `java.vim` file.
I actually want to highlight all the braces, but when there is a square bracket inside normal `()` pair, it won't be highlighted, so I wanted to redefine javaParen to include the `[]` pair, so I want to find the definition of `javaParen`, and include `[]` pair in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search the default syntax with:

```
:vimgrep /javaParen/ $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/*.vim
```

You will see that it is in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/java.vim`, but it's a syntax region `matchgroup`.  A `matchgroup` allows you to use `highlight` to only affect the matches for `start` and `end` on syntax regions, but not the text between them.

It looks like there are actually three syntax regions for `()` and `[]`:

```
" catch errors caused by wrong parenthesis
syn region  javaParenT  transparent matchgroup=javaParen  start="(" end=")" contains=@javaTop,javaParenT1
syn region  javaParenT1 transparent matchgroup=javaParen1 start="(" end=")" contains=@javaTop,javaParenT2 contained
syn region  javaParenT2 transparent matchgroup=javaParen2 start="(" end=")" contains=@javaTop,javaParenT  contained
syn match   javaParenError   ")"
" catch errors caused by wrong square parenthesis
syn region  javaParenT  transparent matchgroup=javaParen  start="\[" end="\]" contains=@javaTop,javaParenT1
syn region  javaParenT1 transparent matchgroup=javaParen1 start="\[" end="\]" contains=@javaTop,javaParenT2 contained
syn region  javaParenT2 transparent matchgroup=javaParen2 start="\[" end="\]" contains=@javaTop,javaParenT  contained
syn match   javaParenError   "\]"
```

`javaParenT`, `javaParenT1`, and `javaParenT2` are the syntax group names.  `javaParen`, `javaParen1`, and `javaParen2` are the highlight `matchgroup`s.

Each one contains the next, allowing you to highlight nested braces.  So, what you want is already covered.  You just need to add highlights for them:

```
highlight link javaParen Special
highlight link javaParen1 Keyword
highlight link javaParen2 Type
```

Here's a screenshot with the highlights above:

[image]

Comment: So, when I do `matchgroup=somthing` , I'm actually defining a matchgroup ? I used to think that `matchgroup` is something that is used to tell vim that this syntax group's highlighting style matches the other already defined syntax group. XD

Comment: @Harshiv It's defining a `highlight` group, actually.  It's pretty confusing since the vocabulary in the docs have `match` and `group` meaning `syntax` groups.  What helps me remember is reading it as: `Match's (highlight) Group`.